# Some of the expectations of great expectations are not working

Tags: pandas, great-expectations

Im trying to run some expectations on my data, some are working fine, but others no, i checked across several versions of the library, and in all of them i having the same issue.

version:

0.18.5

error:

'PandasDataset' object has no attribute 'expect_column_values_to_not_be_null_and_column_to_not_be_empty'

code:

```
import great_expectations as ge
import pandas as pd
df_asset = ge.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], 'B': [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]}))
print(df_asset)
df_asset.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null_and_column_to_not_be_empty("A")
```

but, when trying other kind of expectations like this one (df_asset.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null("A")), it works fine:

```
    {
      "success": true,
      "expectation_config": {
        "expectation_type": "expect_column_values_to_not_be_null",
        "kwargs": {
          "column": "A",
          "result_format": "BASIC"
        },
        "meta": {}
      },
      "result": {
        "element_count": 3,
        "unexpected_count": 0,
        "unexpected_percent": 0.0,
        "unexpected_percent_total": 0.0,
        "partial_unexpected_list": []
      },
      "meta": {},
      "exception_info": {
        "raised_exception": false,
        "exception_traceback": null,
        "exception_message": null
      }
    }
```